# Count number of distinct IDs per days used

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following general structure, containing a work-week's worth of transactions, each associated to a Card ID:

```
CardID----Time(timestamp)
1         2017-07-31 13:03:00
1         2017-08-03 14:00:01
1         2017-08-03 19:32:33
2         2017-08-01 09:09:09
2         2017-08-01 12:03:45
3         2017-08-02 15:31:00
4         2017-08-02 20:09:10
4         2017-08-04 10:38:12
5         2017-07-31 11:35:03
5         2017-08-01 11:30:12
5         2017-08-02 11:32:53
5         2017-08-03 11:43:31
5         2017-08-04 11:12:21
```

I am seeking to return a simple list of activity per day per distinct ID, but the specific day does not matter, nor do the actual number of transactions per day. In essence, the code should return something like this:

```
DaysInWeek----#Cards
1             2
2             2
3             0
4             0
5             1
```

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
select distinct dow
,count(distinct id)
from (
select distinct id,
count(date_trunc('day', tiempo2)) as dow
from public.etapas
group by 1
)a 
group by 1
```

However, it returns 89 rows of DaysInWeek, ranging from 1 to 113. I am lost as to where this error could be coming from, but suspect that it has to do with `date_trunc` and the date format (timestamp). However, when I run a simpler code that just returns the `dow`, there are only 5 rows, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want:

```
select numdays, count(*) 
from (select id, count(distinct date_trunc('day', tiempo2)) as numdays
      from public.etapas
      group by id
     ) e
group by numdays
order by numdays;
```